# get CultureInfo from a Currency Code?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I need to get the System.Globalization.CultureInfo for different Currency Codes.

Examples: EUR, GBP, USD

Currently I am doing the following inside a switch statement based on this 3 letter currency code, obviously this is not the way to do it:

```
var ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
```

Anyone have a clean way to achieve the same results using the currency code's instead?

Comment: What culture would you expect to get from EUR, when there are multiple cultures with the same currency?

Comment: Many cultures share currencies. How are you going to map this? What does EUR map to, for example?

Comment: I guess that answers my question, I would want fr-FR, so I will have to create a lookup table for the results I want - thanks Jon Skeet!

Comment: How did you resolve this @Slee

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Short: That's not possible. EUR for example would map to de-DE, fr-FR, nl-NL and other countries. There is no mapping from Currency to culture, because multiple countries share currencies.

Answer (score 28):

```
static IEnumerable<CultureInfo> GetCultureInfosByCurrencySymbol(string currencySymbol)
{
    if (currencySymbol == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("currencySymbol");
    }

    return CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
        .Where(x => new RegionInfo(x.LCID).ISOCurrencySymbol == currencySymbol);
}
```

For example

```
foreach (var culture in GetCultureInfosByCurrencySymbol("GBP"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(culture.Name);
}
```

prints:

```
cy-GB
gd-GB
en-GB
```

Comment: All I needed was a lookup between ISO code ("GBP") and the number of dec places to use (2), so this method worked for me.  I just took the first culture and used culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits to build a lookup on startup.  This assumes all cultures sharing a currency use the same number of dec places, which is a good enough assumption for my porpoises.

Comment: I needed the currency symbol, number of decimals, and position of currency symbol, for an ISO code. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your looking for

```
var region = new System.Globalization.RegionInfo.CurrentRegion();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo.aspx